# Why do I get an error when saving an image?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

please tell me why I get this error?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()
```

The error refers to the line below. An error occurs when saving the image after editing:

```
surfaceView = new PhotoEditor(this, bitmap, arrowArrayList);
                setContentView(surfaceView);
```

My java code:

```
 relativeLayoutPhoto = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutPhoto);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        int width;
        int height;
        float ratioToMedium;
        sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_DISPLAY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        width = sharedPreferences.getInt(WIDTH_KEY, 0);
        height = sharedPreferences.getInt(HEIGHT_KEY, 0);
        ratioToMedium = sharedPreferences.getFloat(RATIO_TO_MEDIUM_KEY, 0);

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, (int) (height - toolBarHeight * ratioToMedium),false);
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
        relativeLayoutPhoto.setBackground(drawable);
        relativeLayoutPhoto.setOnDragListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you write your **bitmap** width and height and also values of every argument in this method?

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, (int) (height - toolBarHeight * ratioToMedium),false);
```

Comment: Yes. decreasing the value degrades the image quality. Even if you put width 300 and height 300, then an error popped up. The image is also rotated 90 ° and stretched to fill the entire screen. And I don’t know how to fix it.